# Overriding "solve may be ignoring assumptions" in Maple

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, maple

I am trying to solve a system of equations in Maple, but when I have it computing, I get a warning that says "solve may be ignoring assumptions on the input variables."

**The Set-Up**

My equations are polynomials in $x$ defined as letters $t$ through $z$ and coefficients as $a$ through $h$. I want to get expressions for the coefficients, which should be possible with 6 equations and 6 unknowns. These coefficients are defined as greater than zero since they correspond with forward moving rates. The set up is as follows:

```
t:= equation1, assume a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0, etc

u:= equation2, assume a>0,b>0...

...

z:= equation3,assume a>0,b>0...

solve({t,u,v,w,x,y,z},{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h})
```

**Alternative Set-Up**

I have also tried putting the same list of assumptions within the solve command, but I get the same error.

```
solve({equations},{variables},{assume a>0, etc})
```

The first few times I tried either of these, Maple would give me an answer that made $a=0$ and $b=0$, but now it won't even give me these trivial solutions, which is confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maple's "assume" command doesn't work well. In particular, solve may not always know how to solve the system with the restrictions specified by the assumptions.

Comment: I recommend avoiding Maple's "assume" command entirely. Just apply the restrictions yourself _after_ solving.

Comment: I would, but it will give me solutions like a=0 and b=b which I can't go back through and correct without re-solving the system of equations.

Comment: If it's one particular system you are trying to solve, you could post it as a separate question, indicating that a symbolic computer solution is OK, preferably a Maple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `solve(..., useassumptions = true)` to ask `solve` to make sure it uses those assumptions.

Note that it is usually a better idea to put in the inequations directly into the system rather that as assumptions *for the purposes of calling solve*.

The help page `solve/details` (i.e. do `?solve,details` in Maple) documents all the options that solve takes.